# Convert .jar file to JAVA DOC

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

How can I put my jar file to web. i.e is there a software that decompile jar file and make html pages of it?
In other words I want to make a java doc.

Comment: jar to html..!! can you expand it a bit more ?

Comment: A jar file is a simple compressed ZIP archive - what would decompile it? What would a jar file look like in HTML?

Comment: Do you want to make Java doc for a jar?

Comment: Yes I want to make Java doc for a jar.

Comment: Try to get source of that jar.Then use some IDE to generate javadoc. May be Java doc will be available from where you have downloaded the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a **JAVADOC** from a **jar** file that is not created by you i.e you don't have its source code.

Its simple but tricky.

1. Get source code from .jar file by using java decompiler. I use [JD-GUI | Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)
2. Make a new project in myEclipse and copy the 'source code' in source folder.
3. In **project** menu you will see **Generate Javadoc**. Click and select you project and follow the steps. Java doc will be ready after you finish it.

Cheers

[Imran Tariq](http://www.imrantariq.com)

Answer (score 2):

[Edit according to user comment]

So you want to extract javadoc from a jar...

First you must understand that if your jar doesn't contain the sources, but only the compiled code that your javadoc will not show any comment.

Then you just need to extract the file in your jar using any zip program (for exemple on windows, rename file to .zip, and extract it).

Last thing to do, is to call the javadoc tool on it. Like other said you can use an IDE for that, or simply call from the command line :

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#examples

```
javadoc -d \home\html -sourcepath \home\src -subpackages java -exclude java.net:java.lang
```

Comment: I want to make Java doc for a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Javadoc the way it was intended works, as far as I know, only from sources. If the JAR file also contains the source files, then it's just a matter of writing a Java program that opens the JAR file and puts any source files through the javadoc utility.

Interesting idea, but I don't know of anything doing that at the moment. To my knowledge it is however possible to generate Javadoc from [inside of java program](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically).

Another approach would be to load the classes into your classpath and use reflection to figure out methods, fields, etc. It will give you a rough overview of the classes, but sadly not the detailed stuff "normal" javadoc generation gives you. A lot of information is discarded upon compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Converting .jar file to html seems impossible, except if you intend to users to download the .jar file from the web. However, html to .jar is possible.

I am certain that only the java source can be converted to javadoc. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html) to convert java source to javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Once you downloaded your APK file , You need to do the following steps to get a editable java code/document.

1. Convert your apk file to zip (while start your download don't go
   with `save` option , just go with `save as` and mention your
   extension as .zip) by doing like this you may avoid APKTOOL...
2. Extract the zip file , there you can find **somefilename.dex**. so
   now we need to convert dex -> .class
3. To do that, you need `dex2jar`(you can download it from
   [here](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)  , after extracted, in
   command prompt you have to mention like,
        **[here]** (Keep in mind that your **somefilename.dex** must be inside the same folder where you
   have keep your dex2jar.)
4. Download jad from
   http://www.viralpatel.net/blogs/download/jad/jad.zip and
   extract it. Once extracted you can see two files like "jad.exe" and
   "Readme.txt" (sometimes "jad.txt" may there instead of "jad.exe", so
   just rename its extension as.exe to run)
5. Finally, in command prompt you have to mention like **[D:\jad>jad
   -sjava yourfilename.class]** it will parse your class file into editable java document.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mvn javadoc:javadoc` in Maven.