# Javadoc out of the jars that have a java file inside

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have many jar files and each of them have a .java file inside the folder tree that contains the description of method used in a class. As I export each jar to the build path in Eclipse, the help is also available. Is there a way to automatically generate one big javadoc out of all those jars?

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert .jar file to JAVA DOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817653/convert-jar-file-to-java-doc)

Comment: Not really. I have hundreds of jars and each jar may have .java file inside. Out of all of them I need to create javadoc.

Comment: bash script, powershell...?